# How to find out version of sqlite3 in rails 3 app under windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

This seems to be an easy question. However we have hard time to find the answer. Tried `rails dbconsole` and it gives error:

```
Couldn't find database client: sqlite3, sqlite3.exe. Check your $PATH and try again.
```

Some post suggests downloading the sqlite3.exe and run `rails dbconsole` again. However we are not sure if the version# returned is the version# of sqlite3 in rails app. There must be a way to find out the sqlite3 version used in rails app. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bundle show sqlite3` will show you the version of the gem you are using.

Comment: The sqlite3 gem version and the sqlite3 version are not the same.

Comment: Here is the error for bundle exec sqlite3 --version: bundler: command not found: sqlite3
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`

Comment: is the `sqlite3` gem included in your Gemfile? have you done a `bundle install`?  What happens when you do `bundle show sqlite3`?